# seeking a reference for a result stated by Woodin in "Suitable Extender Models I"

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals

In Section 2.1 of the first part of his two-part paper "Suitable Extender Models" Woodin states the following result as Theorem 5:

Suppose that $\delta$ is a limit of Woodin cardinals and that $T$ is a tree on $\omega\times\kappa$ for some $\kappa$. Then the following are equivalent.

(1) $T$ is $(<\delta)$-weakly homogeneous. 
(2) There is a tree $S$ on $\omega\times\delta$ such that for all $\mathbb{P}\in V_{\delta}$, if $G\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is $V$-generic then in $V[G]$,

$$p[T]=\mathbb{R}^{V[G]}\setminus p[S]. $$

This result doesn't seem to be stated in the set of notes "The Stationary Tower". I was wondering if anyone knew a reference for it.

Comment: Have you looked at the paper on universally Baire sets by Feng, Magidor and Woodin (I think)?

Comment: I hadn't seen that one. I've just requested it on ResearchGate. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The perfect reference for this is

> [MR2562557 (2010j:03061)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2562557) Reviewed. Steel, J. R.(1-CA).
>   *[The derived model theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/logic-colloquium-2006/derived-model-theorem/63B1721D044F0A17B68A441E462A32E1)*. In **Logic Colloquium 2006. 
>   Proceedings of Annual European Conference on Logic of the Association for Symbolic Logic held at the Radboud University, Nijmegen, July 27–August 2, 2006**, S. B. Cooper, H. Geuvers, A. Pillay and J. Väänänen, eds., Lecture Notes in Logic, 32. Association for Symbolic Logic, Chicago, IL; Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2009, pp. 280–327.

A preprint can be accessed from John Steel's [website](https://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/Publications.html). If you are not already familiar with universally Baire sets, then I also recommend you read the original reference (mentioned by Asaf in a comment), mainly because it is beautiful mathematics, but John's paper is self-contained and addresses this result explicitly.